# Generate numbers with specific correlation matrix

Tags: random-generation

I have data for 200 respondents to 12 items likert scale(1-9).
Using the correlation matrix and the means of the 12 items, i tried to simulate 1000 respondents using the syntax:

```
out_r <- round(as.data.frame(rmvnorm(1000, mean =  c(7.41,7.19,6.97,7.20,5.75,5.62,5.84,6.03,6.11,5.91,6.35,6.81),sigma = sigma,method = "eigen")), digits =0)
```

where sigma is the correlation matrix.

1. The new data have likert scale (1-11) I don't know how to constrain this range to be like my original data (1-9).
2. `rmvnorm` returned normally distributed data. I wonder if I could get skewed distribution?

Comment: R [psych](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/) library has functions for generating simulated test data, including simulating based on model.

Comment: Its no surprise that your generated data are on in different range if you use the correlation instead of the covariance matrix for simulation.

Comment: @JulianKarls I used Covariance matrix and got different range as well. Thank you.

Comment: Another problem is that you assume your data were generated by a normal distribution even though they obviously were not. There are modelling packages around for ordinal data.